# Return the future that gets executed first with a specific condition on the response

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, future, completable-future

I am trying to make 3 rest calls using completablefutures and return for the first one that matches a specific response. Below is sample test code I wrote (Minus the rest calls) for it but that does not seem to work. I always see "future1" getting returned even with the wait time, which means, test2 and test3 are blocking. How do I achieve the ask?

I thought of using CompletableFuture.anyOf but that just returns the result for the first future that gets executed. Not the first one that matches a specified response. Please advise

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        CompletableFuture<String> combinedFuture = test("future1", 10000)
                .thenCompose(response1 -> test2()
                        .thenCompose(response2 -> test3()
                                .thenApply(response3 -> {
                                    return combine(response1, response2, response3);
                                })));
        System.out.println(combinedFuture.get());
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> test(String str, int i) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return str;
        });
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> test2() {
        return test("future2", 0);
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> test3() {
        return test("future3", 0);
    }

    private static String combine(String response1, String response2, String response3) {
        String responseString = null;
        if (response1 != null) {
            return response1;
        } else if (response2 != null) {
            return response2;
        } else if (response3 != null) {
            return response3;
        }
        return responseString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can race the futures against each other and delegate completions to another one:

```
static <T> CompletableFuture<T> first(Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    var delegate = new CompletableFuture<T>();

    runAsync(() ->
         futures.forEach(future ->
             future.handle(
                 (value, error) -> {
                     if (value == null) {
                         return delegate.completeExceptionally(error);
                     } else {
                         return delegate.complete(value);
                     }
                 })));

    return delegate;
}
```

The future returned by `first` completes (either successfully or with an error), whenever the first one passed in the `futures` argument completes.

Now

```
CompletableFuture<String>  combinedFuture =
    first(Stream.of(test("future1", 10000), test2(), test3()));

System.out.println(combinedFuture.get());
```

prints either "future2" or "future3" depending on which on happens to complete first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a specific task that will collect the result of the others and complete only when desired.

For instance:

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        
        String result = aggregator(
                Arrays.asList(
                        test("future1", 10000),
                        test("future2", 0),
                        test("future3", 0)),
                (value) -> { return value != null; },
                "default value"
                ).get();
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
    private static CompletableFuture<String> aggregator(Collection<CompletableFuture<String>> tasks, Predicate<String> validator, String defaultValue)
    {
        CompletableFuture<String> a = new CompletableFuture<String>();
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
        
        tasks.forEach((t) -> {
            t.whenComplete((value, error) -> { 
                int c = count.incrementAndGet();
                if( error == null && validator.test(value) ) a.complete(value);
                else if( c == tasks.size() ) a.complete(defaultValue);
            }); 
        }); 
        
        return a;
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> test(String str, int i) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return str;
        });
    }
}
```

The `aggregator` method will accept any number of other tasks and will compare the result of each using the `validator` provided. The first one that matches is returned immediately without waiting for the others.

And at the end, if none matched, it completes with the default value.